# NUnit test results and reportunit

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, nunit, reportunit

I am currently using NUnit in Visual Studio to execute my Selenium tests. What I want is some good reporting and I found ReportUnit.

What I cannot seem to figure out is where NUnit places the test result xml files on my machine. I am no tech-wiz so I am struggling to find out how to get ReportUnit working. I found the documentation here: http://relevantcodes.com/reportunit/

But cannot quite figure out how to get my test result files in a specific folder and then open them with ReportUnit.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards,
Anand

Comment: ReportUnit was deprecated by extentreports-dotnet-cli just today. ReportUnit repo is also archived and it will no longer be possible to raise issues there. The project owner @anshooarora will be releasing both the sources and nuget package in a few days. Link: github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-dotnet-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--out` option of nunit3-console.exe to specify where the result file should go. e.g.

`nunit3-console.exe MyTests.dll --out=C:/TestResult.xml`

Comment: I read those commands, but I am also not really a pro with cmd. When I look in my explorer where nunit3-console.exe is located, I see quite a few results (some could be trash) When I go to one of these locations in cmd and use the --out option, I get the message: 'nunit3-console.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: How are you running NUnit at the moment, are you using the NUnit 3 VS adapter? That doesn't produce the xml file that ReportUnit requires - you'll need to download and use the nunit3-console instead.

Comment: Ah that could explain some stuff yes. I am using the NUnit 3 VS adapter. Is ReportUnit not useable in combination with the adapter?

Comment: ReportUnit requires the NUnit xml file, which the VS adapter doesn't write out. Download the nunit3-console from the link below, the second link is docs on how to use. https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/releases
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

You can then use the `--out` option, to get the TestResult.xml file to where you require it.

Comment: Great - glad you're up and running!